# Is it possible to have multi line assignment in Python?

Tags: python, line, variable-assignment

Example of nasty assignment using __ setitem __:

```
self.outer_scopes[self.children.item(i).getNodeName()][self.children.item(i).item(j).getNodeName()] = self.children.item(i).item(j).getTextContent()
```

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
self.outer_scopes[self.children.item(i).getNodeName()][self.children.item(i).item(j).getNodeName()] 
= 
self.children.item(i).item(j).getTextContent()
```

I mean, to split the assignment, not the strings after it with \ or whatever.

Comment: you shouldn't access attributes over 5 levels. Probably you have done some mistake in design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brackets, just like parentheses, invoke implicit line continuation:

```
self.outer_scopes[
    self.children.item(i).getNodeName()
    ][
    self.children.item(i).item(j).getNodeName()
    ] = self.children.item(i).item(j).getTextContent()
```

That said, this screams out for at least a *little* refactoring, since you access `self.children.item(i)` three times.

```
item_i = self.children.item(i)
self.outer_scopes[
    item_i.getNodeName()
    ][
    item_i.item(j).getNodeName()
    ] = item_i.item(j).getTextContent()
```

Answer (score 8):

You could use the backslash:

```
self.outer_scopes[self.children.item(i).getNodeName()][self.children.item(i).item(j).getNodeName()] \
= \
self.children.item(i).item(j).getTextContent()
```

But that's pretty poor style. In this case, I'd use intermediate variables to make the assignment easier to read, if possible.

Answer (score 5):

Use variables to shorten your expression. Would find better names, if I know more context:

```
item_i = self.children.item(i)
item_j = item_i.item(j)
outer_scope = self.outer_scopes[item_i.getNodeName()]
outer_scope[item_j.getNodeName()] = item_j.getTextContent()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use line breaks arbitrarily in side brackets (`[]` or `()` or `{}`) in Python.

```
self.outer_scopes[
    self.children.item(i).getNodeName()
][self.children.item(i).item(j).getNodeName()
] = self.children.item(i).item(j).getTextContent()
```

is valid but it probably won't win you any style points.

You could also always:

```
foo = self.children.item(i).getNodeName()
bar = self.children.item(i).item(j).getNodeName()
self.outer_scopes[foo][bar] = self.children.item(i).item(j).getTextContent()
```

There is also the `\` method (although I personally don't like this):

```
self.outer_scopes[
    self.children.item(i).getNodeName()][self.children.item(i).item(j).getNodeName()] = \
 self.children.item(i).item(j).getTextContent()
```